# How do I connect remote control ceiling fan to fan box with four house wires (two white, two black?)

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan

I’m replacing very old ceiling fans in our house. Each the old fans have lights controlled by one switch and the fan controlled by another switch. The house wires in the ceiling fan box connect to the old fans as follows:

- 2 white house wires to 1 white fan wire
- 1 black house wire to 1 blue fan wire
- 1 black house wire to 1 grayish(?) fan wire (hard to tell color, paint all over it)
- Ground house wire to green fan wire

The new ceiling fans have a remote control. The receiver has one white wire and one black wire, and there are a couple of green wires for grounding.

Is this the right connection:

- Both white house wires to white fan receiver wire
- Both black house wires to black fan receiver wire
- (Ground to both green fan wires, of course)

Comment: Other than this fan/light, are there *other* light switches there which control *other* lights in the room?  Or is the fan-light the only light in the room?

Comment: The latter. There is only the fan light.

Comment: What make and model are your new ceiling fans?

Comment: Home Decorators Windward IV 52 inch